# parsing logs through grok filter

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, syslog

I am trying to parse the values in this log entry by grok filter

```
type=disassociation radio='0' vap='0' client_mac='F6:A5:64:8F:31:20' channel='11' reason='1' instigator='5' duration='957.917574050' auth_neg_dur='0.069978132' last_auth_ago='957.847595918' is_wpa='1' full_conn='1.549515776' ip_resp='1.549515776' ip_src='10.128.20.31' http_resp='1.619493908' arp_resp='1.549515776' ar`p_src='10.128.11.50' dns_server='100.55.333.444' dns_req_rtt='0.039987504
```

my code snippet is

```
if "type=" in [contents] {
           grok {
               match => ["contents", "(type=)(?<auth_type>disassociation|association|wpa_auth)?([ ])(radio=)(')(?<radio>?:[+-]?(?:[0-9]+))(')([ ])(vap=)(')(?<vap>(?:[+-]?(?:[0-9]+)))(')([ ])(client_mac=)(')%({MAC:client_mac})(')"]
           }
```

I am having a `target of repeat operator is not specified` error. Don't understand where am I going wrong in this

Comment: what output are you expecting?

Comment: There's an error in your regex, there's a `?` after `<radio>` that creates an error. You can easily see this by pasting your pattern in https://regex101.com/. Also it would be easier to use the [kv](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html) plugin to deal with this type of key-value pairs.

Comment: The kv plugin did all for me. Thanks @baudsp !

Answer (score 0):

Update to my query -- found the solution!

The kv plugin did all the job of parsing out fields which have `key=value` syntax.
I installed the plugin and just added 
`kv {}` below the grok filter and it parsed out every key value nicely.